# Unable to install rmagick, ruby 1.9, rails 3, windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, ruby-1.9, rmagick

I've been googling for a while but couldn't find anything that works.

Basically, when I put gem 'rmagick' in my gemfile and run bundle install, I get the following error message:

---

Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `rescue in block in buil
d_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

---

I went to the RMagick site and installed the windows binary gem. but it still doesn't work.

What should I do?

Edit: I need rmagick for simple_captcha

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails RMagick on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473853/ruby-on-rails-rmagick-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

Alright finally got it to work.
This is what ended up helping me get it right.

http://www.waydotnet.com/blog/2010/02/rmagick-on-ruby-1-9-1-i386-mingw32-work-d/

Funny thing is, I ended up giving up simple_captcha because of other problems.
Using third party plugins involves much bigger headaches than I thought...

Answer (score 0):

You need ImageMagick installed first.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I thought I had imagemagick installed correctly but that didn't turn out to be the case. It took a lot more work after getting imagemagick to make it work, but that was the first required step.

Comment: ImageMagick is a pain to install. Some OSs have packages that make it easier.  Just did an Ubantu install no problem.  Mac was no problem.  CentOS was a bit more complex. I've never done a windows setup but I can understand how it could be difficult.

Comment: it's as painful as getting your family jewels polished by sandpaper.