# Ruby on Rails RMagick on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

Alright, I've been trying to install Rmagick on a Windows 7 x64 machine pretty much all day. I've checked out every single tutorial on Stack Overflow and other sites, but I keep getting an "Invalid Drive Specification" error no matter which tutorial I follow. My environment came from http://railsinstaller.org/. Has anyone successfully installed Rmagick recently that can point me in the right direction? Thanks, this is driving me crazy but I really have to get it working.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First and most important, when reporting issues or asking for help, **always** include version information about what you're trying to install, specially Ruby.

It seems you're installing using RailsInstaller, but since you didn't mention if is the 2.0 preview version or the stable one, I'll assume you used the stable one, which is based on Ruby 1.8.7-p334.

Now, RailsInstaller already includes the needed pieces: Ruby and RubyInstaller DevKit component, so going to skip the steps about installation of that and jump directly to RMagick itself.

To successfully install RMagick gem, you need ImageMagick binaries *with* development headers, as documented in [RubyInstaller's Tutorial wiki page](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Tutorials), which links [here](http://phosphor-escence.blogspot.com/2010/10/install-rmagick-on-mingw-and-msys.html)

Please download **32bits** version of ImageMagick, as Ruby is 32bits.

For my test I've downloaded the installer version `ImageMagick-6.7.0-8-Q16-windows-dll.exe`

Once downloaded and installed in a path **without spaces** and I've selected the option *Install development headers and libraries for C and C++*.

Then open a new Command Prompt, ensure Ruby is available (checking with `ruby -v`) and after performed the following command:

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16\lib --with-opt-include=C:\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16\include
```

That command is going to take considerable amount of time (took 1 minute on my Core 2 Duo) but the end result was:

```
Fetching: rmagick-2.13.1.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.1
1 gem installed
```

Now you can verify RMagick installed successfully using IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> require "rubygems"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require "rmagick"
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Magick::Version
=> "RMagick 2.13.1"
```

Now, if you're using Ruby 1.9.2, last RMagick release is not compatible with it and you will need to build from source. There is another tutorial on RubyInstaller wiki that covers that, but please read [this thread at RubyInstaller group](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/c837c4438d91208b) were we discuss the issues.

Hope all this helps.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this for me, but I still get an "Invalid Drive Specification" error when I attempt the gem install. My versions are 1.8.7 for Ruby and 3.0.9 for Rails. I followed the instructions exactly, but still the same results I was getting with all the other tutorials on this subject. Any ideas?

Comment: Alright, I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. I have been using the Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails to do all of my command line actions, and I think that was messing up the paths. I switched to the regular Windows command prompt and it went right through.

Comment: After one day trying many solutions, this worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It worked using the ImageMagick 6.7.7 and Ruby 1.9.3. One interesting detail: First I installed the 64b version and it failed. Then, I tried 32 bits, as in this answer, and it worked! Even though my windows is 64b.

Comment: @TiagoFarias 64bits Windows can run 32bits applications. You need to know that Ruby is 32bits. Only at Ruby 2.0.0 we introduced a 64bits version, but for that to work you need all the involved libraries and dependencies have 64bits versions available.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! Just a note I first tried on the Git Bash and it failed "ERROR:  Error installing rmagick: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension." But then used Console2 for windows and it installed successfully

Answer (score 2):

This above post did not work for me, the key for me was using GitBash wich comes with RailsInstaller, and also includes Devkit.

**Install railsinstaller** -> [www.railsinstaller.org](http://%20www.railsinstaller.org) (I installed it to c:\Rails)
**Install ImageMagick** -> [ImageMagick-6.7.3-8-Q16-windows-dll.exe](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.7.3-8-Q16-windows-dll.exe) (I installed it to c:\ImageMagick)
**Open GitBash**

```
$ gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick/include
```

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.13.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rmagick-2.13.1...
```

Also, in the gemfile I have **commented out gem 'rmagick'** in the development group

**This is what my gemfile looks like**

```
group :development do #this is used on localhost
 gem 'mysql2'
 gem 'paperclip'
 #gem 'rmagick' #dont need this
 gem 'devise'
end
```

```
group :production do #this is used on heroku
 gem "pg" #this is postgresql used on heroku
 gem "aws-s3" #this is used for amason S3 filestorage

 gem 'paperclip'
 gem 'rmagick'
 gem 'devise'
end
```

Comment: this version was deleted version not found when click on url , do you know any other solution ?

Answer (score 2):

We just had this problem with Windows 7, Ruby 2.0 & Rails 4.0

[This tutorial](https://adhirajrankhambe.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/installing-rmagick-on-windows/) works really well:

1. [Download the latest ImageMagick installer from ImageMagick.org](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) (as of writing, "[ImageMagick-6.8.7-0-Q16-x86-dll.exe][3]" -- the complete installer (not the binaries))
2. Once downloaded, install ImageMagick without *any* white spaces in the file path (E.G C:/ImageMagick) with the following options checked:

- Add Application Directory To Your System Path
- Installer Development Headers For Libraries C & C++

3. In the Ruby CMD, install the RMagick Gem with the **correct file paths**:

`gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=**c:/ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16/lib** --with-opt-include=**c:/ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16/include**`

This should work for you

Answer (score 0):

I did install it about a month ago. One of many errors I had to overcome was the "Invalid drive specification"

I've just started a blog with a [post](http://blog.bloomingame.com/?p=3) about installing RMagick on Win7 based on my [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811388/imagemagick-core-rl-magick-dll-not-found-or-how-to-install-rmagick-on-window) here.
One note though: I used ruby 1.9.2 and railsinstaller seem to use 1.8.7.

If I remember it right, this error could be caused by spaces in your image magick installation path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enought privileges, sorry for posting my comment to Luis Lavena's answer here.

One solution that worked for me was running Luis Lavena's solution from "Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails" (from the Windows start menu). It loads all necessary configurations.