# How to install Rmagick and imageMagick for Ruby on Rails in windows 7 32 bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rmagick

i need to install Rmagick for my app so 
i have searched allmost all related my question on web and stakeoverflow too but non of these worked for me. 
 i have followed this too but not worked

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473853/ruby-on-rails-rmagick-on-windows-7
```

> My Ruby version -> 1.9.3
>
> Rails version -> 3.2.9
>
> ImageMagick version ->ImageMagick-6.8.3-2-Q16-x86-dll.exe
>
> i have installed ImageMagick here -> C:\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16

i opend CMD then typed

> gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\lib --with-opt-include=C:\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\include

Error is

```
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        d:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-opt-lib=C:ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16lib --with-opt-include=C:ImageMagick-6.8
.3-Q16include
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=d:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in d:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to d:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

Comment: are you sure that ImageMagic binaries are in your *PATH*? Try **identify** command in console.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand what you mean. @roman.brodetski

Comment: just try to type **identify** in console and look if it finds the executable. **identidy** is one of the imagemagick commands

Comment: I found  solution and its worked

http://rorashish.blogspot.in/2012/08/installing-rmagick-with-imagemagic-on.html?showComment=1361352867117#c6064848176479520219

Comment: It may not be of use to you now, but when I had issues with RMagick on windows I found that [minimagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) was a thousand times easier! No dependency problems and easy to deploy on linux as well.

Comment: @Gagan - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> I found solution and its worked http://rorashish.blogspot.in/2012/08/installing-rmagick-with-imagemagic-on.html

~ answer per [Gagan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1845041/gagan)

See the link above for the full details, but the high-level steps (as of 2012 August 9) are:

1. Install Ghostscript
2. Install Imagemagick (use the 32-bit version, as the 64-bit is not working)
3. Restart the console/cmd prompt/IDE/... (or windows)
4. Install rmagick