# Can't install imagemagick for rails on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

I am new to ruby on rails, and need an upload image and upload file control. I saw this (http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip) and it is what I need. But for the image resizing feature, it says it needs imagemagick. 
I have been basically all day trying to install this, following multiple tutorials which are pretty much like this (https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Windows), or telling me to use the rmagick gem from rubyforge.org (which seems to be down since 2013).

When I follow the instructions I always get the following error when running gem install rmagick:

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or header.
```

Could anyone please point me to an up to date tutorial or way of installing imagemagick? Or am I using something too old, I read on a post it has not been committed for years on github?

Also, if there is a better and easier way to upload files and images with rails, suggestions are welcome, as I don't HAVE to use paperclip and imagemagick.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest installing a copy of Ubuntu to work with. Windows and rails is highly incompatible and some gems are dependent on Linux processes. I'm not sure for ImageMagick, but it might be.

Comment: While I agree with @Mingsheng that WIndows is not the best environment for Rails, I still need to ask you which version of ImageMagick did you install?

Comment: I installed this version, ImageMagick-6.9.2-3-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it installed. 
I used version 6.7.9-9 and followed the second answer here (the one where it says to use the Ruby CMD and has some ** in the paths): [Ruby on Rails RMagick on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473853/ruby-on-rails-rmagick-on-windows-7)